# Inserting a period at the end of the array cycle

Tags: c#

```
for(int i = 0; i < org.Length; i++)
{
    if (i < org.Length)
    {
        orgResult += $“{org[i]},“;
        doubledResult += $“{doubled[i]},“;
    }
    else
    {
        orgResult += $“{org[i]}“;
        doubledResult += $“{doubled[i]}“;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine($“\r\nYour original array was [{orgResult}] and now it is doubled it is [{doubledResult}]“);
```

In the code provided I am attempting to put a comma after every element in the array when displaying to the console window. However, when I gets to the last number in the array, I do not want a comma after it.

I thought the else statement would take care of it, but it still puts a comma after the last number. Any suggestions?

Comment: `i < org.Length` --> `i < org.Length - 1` (in the `if` not the loop)

Comment: @NickA Thanks for the response. It works as it should now.

Comment: For adding `","` betwwen array value you can use : `String.Join("MySeparator", myArray)`

Comment: @NickA's comment is right and the reason is the index starts from 0 in C# so last element's index is Length - 1

Comment: For a really big array, the string concatenation in a tight loop will put a lot of pressure on the garbage collector. `String.Join` will be really efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`i` is **always** less than `org.Length`, that's your loop condition. To recognize when it's the last iteration, you need to check `if i < org.Length - 1`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < org.Length; i++)
{
       if (i < org.Length - 1)
```

A better way to solve this would be to use [`string.Join()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join):

```
orgResult = string.Join(",", org);
doubledResult = string.Join(",", doubled);
```

But if this is a school exercise you might not be allowed to use those methods.

Comment: How do you know ``org`` is array string

Comment: @ThierryV why should I? `string.Join` is generic and uses the element's `ToString()` just as OP's string interpolation. I linked the docs, it works for non-string arrays, too.

Comment: @ThierryV if `$“{org[i]},“` worked. I see no reason for `org[i].ToString()` to fail in this `Join`.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is what you want:

```
var strings = new string[] { "a", "b", "c" };
var combinedString = string.Join(",", strings );
```

Result: combinedString ="a,b,c"

Comment: Note that Join can take IEnumerable<string>, which means you can use Linq to produce the component strings from any kind of array.

Comment: `string.Join` uses a `IEnumerable<T>`, it's generic and works for all types (with proper `ToString()` implementation).

Comment: @RenéVogt There is a generic overload, yes, but there is also a specific one for IEnumerable<string>. That one is probably more efficient, and my main intention was to allow custom formatting.

Comment: To be precise: there is no overload taking a `IEnumerable<string>`, only an `string[]`, but yes with a `Select` you could add custom formatting.

Comment: Intellisense shows me five overloads for string.Join: `params object[]`, `params string[]`, `IEnumerable<string>`, string array with startindex and count, and `IEnumerable<T>`

Answer (score 1):

[As I mentioned in my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51401084/inserting-a-period-at-the-end-of-the-array-cycle/51401304#comment89772737_51401084) to fix your code you need to change:

```
if (i < org.Length)
```

into:

```
if (i < org.Length - 1)
```

This is because your loop already forces the requirement of `i` being less than `org.Length` and so your `else` case can never trigger.

However for a more efficient solution you should use `string.Join`, as mentioned in [René's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51401184/3270037).

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem with `string`s in the current code if `org` is big one:

```
int[] org = new int[1000000];
```

since each `orgResult += $“{org[i]},“;` means creating a *new instance* of *immutable* `string` and *copying* data to it (`1000000` creatings multiplied by `500000` average length results in `5e11` elementary operations).
If you want *loop implementation* use `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder sbOrg = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder sbDub = new StringBuilder(); 

foreach (var item in org) {
  if (sbOrg.Length > 0)
    sbOrg.Append(",");

  sbOrg.Append(item);
}

foreach (var item in doubled) {
  if (sbDub.Length > 0)
    sbDub.Append(",");

  sbDub.Append(item);
}

orgResult = sbOrg.ToString();
doubledResult = sbDub.ToString();
```

Comment: always good to explain the problem with **very** large sets of string (there is no real issue with "normally" sized sets), but `string.Join` already does all the optimization, no need to do it yourself again.

Comment: @René Vogt: I have *nothing to add* to your solution with `Join`, but as you've mentioned in your answer it can be a kind of school task (no `Join` is allowed). And there's a antipattern with appending `string` within a loop that's why I've provided my code.

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to accomplish just that,
you can for example change your condition like this:

```
orgResult += $“{org[i]}“;
doubledResult += $“{doubled[i]}“;
if(i != org.Length - 1)
{
   orgResult += ",";
   doubledResult += ",";
}
```

though it's not best practice.